# AWS OpenSearch vs AWS ElasticSearch. The main differences between them

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, opensearch

Amazon Web Services provides two engines when it comes to Amazon OpenSearch Service: ElasticSearch and OpenSearch. Does the Opensearch have any advantages over ElasticSearch. Will the customers get any features along with OpenSearch? I want to mention that my questions is not about the difference between Open-source ElasticSearch and AWS Opensearch difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS has stopped providing updates to Elasticsearch. Due to the license change Elasticsearch made, Amazon can no longer provide managed hosting for newer versions of Elasticsearch.

You have to "upgrade" to OpenSearch to get updates and newer features.

Comment: Are the underlying APIs (index, search, etc.,) still the same?

Comment: @Raj aws has forked opensearch from ES 7.10.2, so apis n queries will be same